# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\NoticeCommentController::destroy() must be an instance of App\NoticeComment, instance of App\Notice given

Tags: laravel

I have a problem in laravel to see this:

[image]

help me please.

**NoticeCommentController.php**:

```
public function destroy(NoticeComment $noticeComment)
{
    $noticeComment->delete();
}
```

but this is not working..

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\NoticeCommentController::destroy() must be an instance of App\NoticeComment, instance of App\Notice given

what is problem..?

my code in github : https://github.com/jonsoku/homepage2

Comment: why don't you make it like this $noticeComment =  New NoticeComment; in destroy function  insted of passing argument

Comment: because i dont know how to make it . : ( cuz im learning now.. how can i fix it ?  please help me

Comment: You are passing an object of different class to the function. Check what exactly you are passing to the function.
you can check it with `dd($noticeComment);` before calling the `destroy` function.

Comment: i use react.. so i cant watch that page : (

Comment: please remove reactjs from tag, it is not relate to react, pure laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this

```
public function destroy(Notice $notice, NoticeComment $noticeComment)
{
    $noticeComment->delete();
}
```

### Explain

when you defined nested resource like this

```
Route::resource('notices.noticeComments', 'NoticeCommentController');
```

your route going to be something like this

```
notices/{notice}/noticeComments/{noticeComment}
```

So your first parameter is going to be `Notice` and second param is `NoticeComment`, hope it help.

You can read more here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: @JLtokyo I just updated my answer, add description and link to learn more.

Comment: @JLtokyo focus on documentation, everything is given in documentation of Laravel.

Comment: I have the same problem, but my problem is a little bit difference, I have two routes:
``Route::apiResource('classrooms.teachers', 'TeacherClassroomController');``
``Route::apiResource('teachers.classrooms', 'TeacherClassroomController');``
Only my delete function crash: 
``public function destroy(Teacher $teacher, Classroom $classroom)``
When I try using the ``classrooms/{classroom}/teachers/{teacher}`` don't work.